# コマンドでファイル比較し、一致しないレコードを抽出する方法

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript, shell, grep

【内容】
コマンドにて、「IDを列挙しているファイル」と、「IDなどが記述されているcsv」を比較し
csvから、「IDを列挙しているファイル」に記載されていないIDのレコードを抽出したいです。

【例】
IDを列挙しているファイル（hogehoge_list）

```
AAAAAA
XXXXXX
ZZZZZZ
```

IDなど様々な情報が記述されているcsv(foofoo.csv)

```
AAAAAA,タイトル,URL
BBBBBB,タイトル,URL
XXXXXX,タイトル,URL
ZZZZZZ,タイトル,URL
```

「hogehoge_list」と「foofoo.csv」を比較して、「hogehoge_list」にないIDである『BBBBBB』の「foofoo.csv」の行を取得したい。

```
BBBBBB,タイトル,URL
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: grep を使って `grep -F -w -v -f hogehoge_list foofoo.csv` とか。

Comment: @metropolis ご回答ありがとうございます！
解決しました！

Comment: @metropolis 他の質問でも同様ですが、「回答」はコメントではなくぜひ「個別の回答」として投稿してください。このままだとシステム的には「未解決」のまませっかくの知見が埋もれてしまうことになります。

Comment: 上の `grep` ですが、この場合は ID に使われた文字列が他の行に現われてはいけません。
（`-w` オプションがあるので、現れても良いケースもあります。詳しくはマニュアルで確認して下さい）
ID の桁揃えなどをしていると、この条件を満たすことも多いと思いますが、念のため。

Answer (score 1):

```
join -t',' -v2 hogehoge_list foofoo.csv
```

[`join`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_coreutils/man1/join.1.html) コマンドの `-v` オプションを利用し、一列目で結合されなかった `foofoo.csv` の行のみを出力しています。両ファイルとも対象の列で**ソートされている必要**があります。

ソートなども含めて書くと、例えば以下のようになります。

```
#!/bin/sh

# エラーで即時終了, > (リダイレクト)による上書き禁止
set -eC

# join コマンドのため、少なくとも一列目はソートされている必要がある
LC_ALL=C sort hogehoge_list -t',' >delete_ids.txt
LC_ALL=C sort foofoo.csv -t',' >all.csv

LC_ALL=C join -t',' -v2 delete_ids.txt all.csv >out.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK でもよろしければ、次の one-liner はいかがでしょうか。

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} !a[$1]' hogehoge_list foofoo.csv
```

- `-F,` でフィールドセパレーターを "," に設定します
- `FNR`が `NR` に等しい時、つまり最初のファイル `hogehoge_list` が読まれている間は `{...}` 内の処理が実行されます。ここで `hogehoge_list` 内のIDが連想配列に蓄えられます
- 2番目のファイル `foofoo.csv` が読まれている間は次の `!a[$1]` が処理されます。つまり`hogehoge_list` に含まれていない時のみ、デフォルト動作である `print` が実行されます

AWKで複数のファイルを処理する際の定番ですが、ご参考まで。